Vault Agent Injector - Use init container only (disable sidecar)
We are using vault injection to source environment variables during container startup.
We only have a need to do this during startup, and do not need to retrieve updates after that point. We have been looking for a way to disable the sidecar injection, but have been unsuccessful so far.
The documentation states the following (emphasis mine):

Next, two types of Vault Agent containers can be injected: init and sidecar. The init container will prepopulate the shared memory volume with the requested secrets prior to the other containers starting. The sidecar container will continue to authenticate and render secrets to the same location as the pod runs. Using annotations, the initialization and sidecar containers may be disabled.

And that's the last it's mentioned. It does not state anywhere which annotations accomplish this, and on the documentation page for annotations does not seem to list any annotations that accomplish this.
Has anyone been able to get this working?

If you only plan on using the init container then any secret updates, renewals, etc. will not propagate to the workload. Is that ok?

@MatthewSchuchard Yes that's correct. We have a startup script that reads the file created from the init container and sources them to the running processes environment.
Secret updates do not need to happen after startup.

I have looked at doing the same. This will save memory.

@kometen yeah, not just memory but we have a large mass of pods constantly making api calls to vault, and it's causing us to have unnecessarily large vault server instances, as well as potentially bottlenecking new pods coming online from other requests

Ok so this may be a bit of a grammar issue. I have only ever understood the annotations to disable either both the init and sidecar, or neither. The documentation does state "the initialization and sidecar containers", and not "the initialization and/or sidecar containers". The capability to disable both or neither is also consistent with the annotation documentation. I think you want a FR here.

@MatthewSchuchard This makes no sense if that's what was intended from the documentation. By default, no init or sidecar containers are injected at all. They're only added when you include an annotation, so an annotation that disables them both would make absolutely no sense, and in fact no annotation to do so even exists either. You simply just don't need to include any annotations if you want neither.

vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject with a value of false is the annotation you are inquiring about to disable both.

@MatthewSchuchard okay, I guess insofar as an annotation has to have a value, it reads a true or false value, but false is just the same as not including any annotation at all. This line of the documentation should simply be removed if they cannot be independently controlled

@kometen
I found the answer, I posted an answer to the question

After digging through the source code for the agent injector, I have been able to track down that the annotation that controls this behaviour is called:
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-pre-populate-only
the documentation for the annotation states the following:

configures whether an init container is the only injected container.
If true, no sidecar container will be injected at runtime of the pod.
Enabling this option is recommended for workloads of type CronJob or
Job to ensure a clean pod termination.

The name of the annotation is what made it hard to find in the list of annotations. The vault documentation should be updated to mention in the bolded line from the question WHICH annotations control this behaviour.
